# Write protect cell after first user entry in Google Spreadsheets or Microsoft Excel

Tags: google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet

How to write protect a cell once any user has written a value to it? Is there a formula? Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. Here's an empty monthly planned tests sheet on [Google spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IyyaDXI33rxZ9tmnEhq-VbqNcFE_2jyLHrLbvwJ6k9w/edit#gid=1713705193). About 60 teachers will have access to it. Their goal is to write in the name of their subject in a certain cell, which will mean they will carry a test on a certain day. Once a certain teacher writes the value, the cell needs to get closed from further edits by other teachers [first in, first out principle].
Some teachers would rewrite the values of their colleagues, some would do that by accident, etc. I would want the system to close the cell and even show a msg if that is possible to avoid rewrites or additions.

According to the law, we can have only 1 test per day in grades 1 to 7, and still some teachers would still try and write their subject when done on paper. Some would horrify me with their handwriting, which requires me to make phone calls, e-mails... So, I'm trying to make a digital transition.

Would appreciate any help. Scripting anyone?

Answer (score 1):

For Google Spreadsheets, you have two options:

1. **Hard way**: create a custom script function that set cell permission. You attach the function to the sheet with [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization?hl=en#permissions_and_types_of_scripts) so that it will run under document owner permission.
2. **Easy way**: use [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/). You can create survey forms that function as the input interface. The editor can only submit new data but not view or edit existing data. You can set the spreadsheet permission to read-only if you want teachers to review data.